# Regex to match URL path segments not containing a symbol

Tags: java, regex

Given URL that may contain zero or many "ID-segments" (a segment that contains `_` character), i.e.:

```
/v1/customer/cus_id/cards/card_id
```

what would be a regex that can find & replace all these segments with predefined string (`[^/]+` in my case), so that end result would look like this:

```
/v1/customer/[^/]+/cards/[^/]+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work 
`[^/]+_[^/]+`
Well at least it worked with your example. 
What I did :

```
String x = "/v1/customer/cus_id/cards/card_id";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll("[^/]+_[^/]+","[^/]+"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace every occurrence of `[^/]+_[^/]` with your string and you are good to go, provided every "ID-segments" all contain "*", and segments that are not "ID-segments" will not contain "*"